# ListView not showing on my app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I created a fragment connected to a list view to display a simple table view.

Here is my fragment:

```
public class ConfRoomListFragment extends Fragment {
    ApplicationController activity;
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conf_room_list, container, false);
        activity = (ApplicationController) getActivity();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.conf_room_directory);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my `fragment_conf_room_list.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/conf_room_directory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `activity_listview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

When I run my app, all that shows is a blank screen. I created the list view and added the adapter. There doesn't seem to be any variable issues, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**EDIT**
I've already added my fragment to the activity:
`ApplicationController.java`

```
/* Instantiate all Fragments needed*/
    directoryViewFragment = new DirectoryViewFragment();
    directoryListFragment = new DirectoryListFragment();
    officeViewFragment = new OfficeViewFragment();
    officeListFragment = new OfficeListFragment();
    confRoomListFragment = new ConfRoomListFragment();
    settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    directionsFragment = new DirectionsFragment();
    airportInfoFragment = new AirportInfoFragment();
    publicationsFragment = new PublicationsFragment();
    practiceGroupListFragment = new PracticeGroupListFragment();
    practiceGroupFragment = new PracticeGroupFragment();
```

As you can see I instantiated my fragment.

This is where the selection occurs:

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position, false);
        System.out.println(position);
        current_position = position;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 */
private void displayView(int position, boolean firstClick) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    if (firstClick) {
        Fragment fragment = directoryViewFragment;
        currentPanel = Panel.HomeView;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    } else {
        new ViewSelectionListener(this).onItemClick(null, null, position, 0);
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
}
```

I know it works because the `setTitle` function works and the title of the fragment is `Conference Rooms`.

This is my `ViewSelectionListener.java`, where I update the Fragment manager to show my fragment:

```
    } else if (position == 2) {

        //Conference Rooms
        activity.setCurrentPanel(Panel.ConfRoomDirectory);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(Tags.TRANSITION_IN, Tags.TRANSITION_OUT)
                // TODO If there are other fragments to hide, put them here!
                .hide(activity.getDirectoryViewFragment())
                .hide(activity.getPublicationsFragment())
                .hide(activity.getSettingsFragment())
                .hide(activity.getAirportInfoFragment())
                .hide(activity.getDirectionsFragment())
                .hide(activity.getPracticeGroupListFragment())
                .hide(activity.getPracticeGroupFragment())
                .hide(activity.getOfficeViewFragment())
                .show(activity.getConfRoomListFragment());

        if (activity.isPhone) {
            transaction.hide(activity.getDirectoryListFragment());
            transaction.hide(activity.getOfficeListFragment());
        } else if (activity.isPortrait()) {
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_left);
            if (DirectoryViewFragment.leftPanelIsShowing) {
                transaction.remove(activity.getDirectoryListFragment());
                DirectoryViewFragment.leftPanelIsShowing = false;
            }
            if (OfficeViewFragment.leftPanelIsShowing) {
                transaction.remove(activity.getOfficeListFragment());
                OfficeViewFragment.leftPanelIsShowing = false;
            }
            if (PracticeGroupFragment.leftPanelIsShowing) {
                transaction.remove(activity.getPracticeGroupListFragment());
                PracticeGroupFragment.leftPanelIsShowing = false;
            }
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

As you can see, I hide all of the other fragments and show the fragment that I wanted. However, only the title get updated, the fragment isn't shown. So the issue doesn't lie with the Activity, there's some other error that I don't see.

Comment: where you inflate your fragment ? Post that code also

Comment: @AnandSavjani its in the first block of code i attached

Comment: add some log to the ConfRoomListFragment's onCreateView() method, e.g. : Log.i("Tag", "onCreateView called") and see if it has been called. If not, then you have some logic error.

Comment: @Serg_ Its not logging, so there is an logic error, but I'm not sure where the logic error is

Comment: try to add some more logs to see what methods are called, e.g. in the ViewSelectionListener's if statements.

Comment: @Serg_ I added a log in the if statement at position 2. It gets called. So my fragment is nonexistent, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Did you add ConfRoomListFragment to the container before call .show(activity.getConfRoomListFragment());? The description of FragmentTransaction's show() method says: "Shows a previously hidden fragment. This is only relevant for fragments whose views have been added to a container, as this will cause the view to be shown."

Comment: @Serg_ I'm not sure where would I add the fragment to the container?

Comment: You need somewhere to call getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentHolder, ConfRoomListFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

Comment: @Serg_ oh I see now i didn't have that method created. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141664/discussion-between-serg-and-varun-iyer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if onCreateView() method of your fragment is really called. If not then your fragment is not added to activity. Make sure to call

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.fragmentHolder, ConfRoomListFragment) .addToBackStack(null) .commit();
```

before you call FragmentTransaction's show(ConfRoomListFragment) method.

If ConfRoomListFragment's onCreate() method is called try to use next constructor of ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter =  = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
```

And change list item (activity_listview.xml) a little bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activity = (ApplicationController) getActivity();
```

Remove above line, this line will never use in this fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conf_room_list, container, false);

     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray);

     ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.conf_room_directory);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     return view;
}
```

> fragment_conf_room_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/conf_room_directory"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see my edited answer, If there still mistake then I am sure that, your fragment not calling from Activity.

Comment: It didn't work. How do I add this fragment to the activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `TextView` layout in adapter if you want use your own layout.

```
public class ConfRoomListFragment extends Fragment {
    ApplicationController activity;
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
        "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conf_room_list, container, false);
        activity = (ApplicationController) getActivity();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.label, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.conf_room_directory);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And for your `ListView` height must be set to `match_parent`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/conf_room_directory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```